# Fastest way to find index of same value in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to optimize below implementation, I have 2 arrays:

```
item= [3,  2,  6, 1,  3,  1,  9,  3]
price=[21, 54, 2, 56, 13, 98, 56, 20]
```

What I need is to get the prices of an item's duplicates (**excluding** its own price).

```
3: [13, 20]
2: []
6: []
1: [98]
3: [21, 20]
1: [56]
9: [56]
3: [21,13]
```

I have my current solution using 2 for loops:

```
for i in range(item):
same=[]
    for j in range(item):
        if item[j]==item[i] and j!=i:
            same.append(price[j])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you have a list of an item's prices then you already know that you can get these "duplicates excluding one price" by just removing one of the prices.

For example (*): If `3: [21, 13, 20]` then you know that the "duplicates excluding one price" are:

```
3: [13, 20]
3: [21, 20]
3: [21, 13]
```

So you should just be able to do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = [3,  2,  6, 1,  3,  1,  9,  3]
prices = [21, 54, 2, 56, 13, 98, 56, 20]

item_to_price = defaultdict(list)
for item, price in zip(items, prices):
    item_to_price[item].append(price)
```

Then you can easily manipulate the values of this dict to obtain (*):

```
# To create the result you want for 3:
def single_removed(lst):
    for rmidx in range(len(lst)):
        yield lst[:rmidx] + lst[rmirx+1:]

# For example for 3:
for sr in single_removed(item_to_price[3]):
    print(f'3: {sr}')

# Will give you:
# 3: [13, 20]
# 3: [21, 20]
# 3: [21, 13]
# as wanted.
```

Comment: This approach will simplify the "item" list removing the duplicates which I would not want... the same "item" list should remain.

Comment: @gellowmellow I'm not sure what you mean, please see my edit. You don't have to remove/delete anything.

Comment: Thanks, clearer after the edits. Have optimized the code further based on this approach.